# Transferring data from Javascript to a php page

Tags: php, javascript

I have a `Javascript` variable in my `file.js` that i want to send to `map.php` then from `map.php` i want the send it to `map2.php`:

**file.js**

```
//some code
$.post('map.php', { latitude: position.coords.latitude , longitude: position.coords.longitude });
//some code
```

**map.php**

```
<?php 
session_start();
$latitude = $_POST['latitude'];//line 26
$longitude = $_POST['longitude'];////line 27
$_SESSION['latitude'] = $latitude;
$_SESSION['longitude'] = $longitude;?>
```

**map2.php**

```
<?php 
session_start();
$latitude = $_SESSION['latitude'];
$longitude = $_SESSION['longitude'];?>
<script>
var myOrigin= new google.maps.latLng(<?php echo json_encode($latitude); ?>,<?php echo json_encode( $longitude ); ?>);
console.log(myOrigin);
</script>
```

On map.php i keep getting these errors:

```
Notice: Undefined index: latitude in C:\wamp\www....  on line 26
Notice: Undefined index: longitude in C:\wamp\www....   on line 27
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Debugging starts here: `var_dump($_POST);` See what's really in there.

Comment: Oh, yeah. You'll need to define a callback function to see the results of var_dump or any other output.

Comment: You should also test your js file: add this before $.post: `window.console.log('latitude is ' + position.coords.latitude + ', ' + 'longitude is ' + position.coords.longitude);` and check the output on your browser debugging tool.

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe the source of the problem is that my Javascript variable only get their values at `window.onload`

Comment: @jeffman where i need to put that `var_dump($_POST)` in my code, what's its role?

Comment: @Hossum. Put it right after the <?PHP tag, like this: `var_dump($_POST); exit;` This is temporary, for debugging only. And temporarily change your ,post function to look like this: `$.post('map.php', { latitude: position.coords.latitude , longitude: position.coords.longitude }, function(data){alert(data)});` so that you can SEE the response from your server.

Comment: @Jeffman It give an alert dialog containing HTML elements and at the end there is a certain <b>array</b><i>(size=2)</i>.

Latitude and longitude give the correct values too.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "map.php",
  data: { latitude: position.coords.latitude , longitude: position.coords.longitude }
}).done(function( msg ) {
  alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
```

Also, in map.php, personally I like to use $_REQUEST vs $_POST.  It picks up both POST and GET variables, rather than having to distinguish between the two.